# Copying multiple attributes to one element

Tags: jquery, attributes, attr

I'm currently having some trouble trying to copy all the attributes from a bunch of list items into the first list item.

I want to add the first list item (All) to the top of the list and then copy all of the data-filter attributes from the elements below into All, so they appear like data-filter=".ant, .bee, .bug, .moth"

here is alink to my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8e4Kv/1/

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks!

Big D

Comment: Do you really want to set the `data-filter` attr, or use jQuery's `data` function? The first time jQuery sees `data-xxx` in an element, it caches it, and never looks at/modifies it again. So, if you set it with `attr`, `data` will return a different value, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like below will do the job,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/8e4Kv/2/)

```
$(function() {

    var $li = $('ul li[data-filter]');

    var allAttr = [];        
    $li.each (function () {
        allAttr.push ($(this).attr('data-filter'));
    });

    $('<li>All</li>')
      .insertBefore('ul li:first-child')
      .attr('data-filter',allAttr.toString());

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `$.each()` function to first loop through each list item's `data-filter` attribute, then assign each of those attributes to your prepended element.